# How to automate creating and managing the Cloudant SDP?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant-sdp

I need to automate setting up the Cloudant SDP process so that devops can ensure that environment setup is repeatable.

One option is to directly manipulate documents in `_warehouser`, but this is akin to messing around with an internal API which is probably asking for trouble?

Is there a public API that I can use for setting up the SDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed with the engineering team that there currently isn't a public API for managing the SDP.